# Multivariate Derivative with constraint [Implicit Function Theorem/Chain rule Application]

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, constraints

I'd love to get some help understanding this question.

*Let* $ w=f(x,y,z) $ *with the constraint* $g(x,y,z)=3.$ *At point* $P(0,0,0)$ *we have* $df = <1,1,2> , dg=<2,-1,-1>.$ *Find the value of P at two quantities:*

$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y$$ and $$\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)_x$$

[Attempt]

Rewriting G as $$G(x,y)=g[x,y;z(x;y)]=3$$

and applying the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}}=- \frac{G_x}{G_z} = - \frac{2}{-1} = + 2 $$

Given the m.v.c. rule:
$$ \frac{\partial w}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

Rewriting w and re-applying the chain rule using the previous result:
$$w = f(x,y,z(x,y))$$ 
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + 0 $$

$$ \left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)_y = \frac{ \partial w}{\partial z}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}} = 2 \hspace{0.1cm} 2 = 4$$

Comment: Nothing remotely to do with Stokes's Theorem, etc. This is an implicit function theorem/chain rule application. The notation should be $$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y,$$ meaning that you hold $y$ fixed when you think of $z=z(x,y)$ on the surface $g(x,y,z)=3$.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the question.

Comment: The second one cannot be correct. You can't hold $x$ constant and differentiate with respect to $x$. Shouldn't it still be holding $y$ constant?

Comment: Yes, that could be a typo. I gave it a try following your pointers but I am not entirely sure if it is correct.

Comment: You lost a minus sign in your first computation, but otherwise good. For the second, you really need to make the subscript a $y$; as I already said, holding $x$ fixed, cannot vary $x$ to compute a partial derivative with respect to $x$. So do the chain rule for $(\partial w/\partial x)_y$, and use your result from the first part.

Comment: Thank you. As you pointed out I applied the first result to the second rewriting. Is it correct?

Comment: No. See my addition to the original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: By the implicit function theorem, the equation $g(x,y,z)=3$ defines $z=z(x,y)$ near $P$. Use the chain rule to differentiate $G(x,y) = g(x,y,z(x,y))$ with respect to $x$. Note that $G(x,y)=3$ for all $x,y$ near $(0,0)$.

Similarly, for the second problem [once it's modified], you want to differentiate $F(x,y) = f(x,y,z(x,y))$ [for the *same* $z(x,y)$] using the chain rule. In particular, you will have
$$\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\right)_y = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}.$$